# guard-haml output to multiple locations

Tags: haml, guard

I would like Guard to send the output of a haml compilation to two different places.  I tried calling haml in my Guardfile twice, like this:

```
guard 'haml', :output => 'first_dir/', :input => 'src/haml' do
  watch %r{^src/haml/.+(\.html\.haml)(?!(\.swp))}
end
guard 'haml', :output => 'second_dir/', :input => 'src/haml' do
  watch %r{^src/haml/.+(\.html\.haml)(?!(\.swp))}
end
```

But that just goes into an endless loop.  What does my Guardfile need to look like to output to two different directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problems with your Guardfile. As workaround you could use groups and start two Guard processes:

```
group :first do
  guard 'haml', :output => 'first_dir/', :input => 'src/haml' do
    watch %r{^src/haml/.+(\.html\.haml)(?!(\.swp))}
  end
end

group :second do
  guard 'haml', :output => 'second_dir/', :input => 'src/haml' do
    watch %r{^src/haml/.+(\.html\.haml)(?!(\.swp))}
  end
end
```

and now you start each in its own terminal:

```
guard -g first
guard -g second
```

Not quite elegant, but it'll work...

Comment: @Gowie47 Thanks for the hint. I updated my answer to correct the wrong groups.

Comment: Cool. Have you ever used groups before? I tried the above method and it created an infinite loop where it just continually calls both haml methods until guard throws a stack exception.

Comment: @Gowie47 Of course I use the group feature (I wrote it), but I don't use the Haml plugin. I often group large Guardfile definitions and run different groups in different terminals, so I have parallel execution for different tasks.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who comes across the above answer and bangs their head against the wall trying to get groups to work Netzpirat got the syntax wrong. The correct syntax is the following:

```
group :iPhone do
    guard 'haml', :input => 'src/haml', :output => '../iPhone/www/' do
        watch %r{^src/haml/.+(\.html\.haml)}
    end
end
```

Thanks still go out to Netzpirat, since I didn't actually know about this feature till this SO question.